# misleading behavior with jar in java with abstract classes

Tags: java

I faced a very strange behavior that i created 2 class in a package say aa.bb

**Code of class aa**

```
         package aa.bb;
         public abstract class aa {
        abstract void deep();
          }
```

**Code of class bb**

```
       public class bb extends aa{
            @Override
        void deep() {
        }
            }
```

Now i created another package say bbc.cc and created one class inside this package.

**Code of class cc**

```
          package bbc.cc;
           import aa.bb.bb;
           public class cc extends bb {
            }
```

Now the cc class is showing the error **This class must implement the inherited abstract method aa.deep(), but cannot override it since it is not visible from cc. Either make the type abstract or make the inherited method visible**

Now a make the jar file of package aa.bb and deleted the aa.bb package from the source code. And added the jar file in the build path. After this the error is coming as previously. Now i added the source code of bb class in aa.bb package and error resolved.
I do not know what is happening behind this.

This is the final directory structure of the project[image]

Please help me to clear the concept

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because the `default` access for any method or class is `package level`.

So, the method `void deep()` is actually visible to the classes which are inside same package `aa.bb`

I would suggest making your method `deep()` public.

```
package aa.bb;
public abstract class aa {
   public abstract void deep();
}
```

and

```
public class bb extends aa{
    @Override
    public void deep() {
    }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes i know by making it public it will work.But i also added another scenario that when a i added the package aa.bb as a jar file in the build path and also deleted the source code of only aa class from aa.bb folder. Then it is not showing any error.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify access specified by default the visibility is `default`  which means the field will be accessible from inside the same package to which the class belongs.

So now your implementation of `deep()` from `bb` is not visible in cc since it is from different package

and since `cc` doesn;t receive the implementation of `deep()` and it indirectly extends `aa` it needs to provide the implementation for abstract methods

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i also added another scenario that when a i added the package aa.bb as a jar file in the build path and also deleted the source code of only aa class from aa.bb folder. Then it is not showing any error.

Comment: _that when a i added the package_ didn't get it

Comment: Oh Sorry. I created another project with just aa.bb package and created a jar of that. Now added that jar into the build path of this project. Now error is same. Now  I added only class bb in the package aa.bb and now  No compile time error.

Comment: Because once you put them in the same package as parent the implementation of method (abstract) available in the class by inheritance so you are not not required to put the implementation of abstract method

Comment: No No I added the bb class in different package than cc class

Comment: so all the classes are in same package now ?

Comment: I added the final directory structure of my project.